# How to put multiple items in a single request?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I use BatchGetItemRequest for getting multiple items across tables in a single request. I would like to do the same for updates i.e. How do i insert/update multiple items across tables in a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

As [somedave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287868/45773) pointed out already (+1), inserting/deleting multiple items across tables similar to getting items across tables via [BatchGetItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchGetItems.html) has meanwhile been added and made available in the [AWS SDKs](http://aws.amazon.com/code) as of April 19, 2012 accordingly, see [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchWriteItem.html) for details.

---

#### Initial Answer

Inserting/Updating multiple items across tables similar to getting items across tables via [BatchGetItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchGetItems.html) isn't available yet for [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) (despite being an obvious feature indeed) - you might want to file a respective feature request in the [Amazon DynamoDB forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=131).

Answer (score 14):

Batch put and delete are available now (they call it BatchWriteItem): http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_BatchWriteItems.html

However, you still can not update multiple items in a single request.

Comment: This is in REST API. It isnt available in language API other than BatchGetItemRequest, IMO.

Comment: I know it's at least available in the .NET API (see the changelog here: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/.NET/6888944574638729)

Comment: @somedave: It's indeed available in all SDKs as of April 19, 2012, I've updated my answer accordingly - thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Comment: Only 25 items at a time process through BatchWriteItem, if you have more than 25 items it won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html#API_TransactWriteItems_RequestSyntax) to update up to 100 items in the same request:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    
response = client.transact_write_items(
    TransactItems = [
        {
            "Update": { 
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "Update": { 
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

For more details and syntax of each "Update" item in the `TransactItems` list: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.transact_write_items

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answers above (for `Load Data`),
I am adding another link that includes code and valid files for example:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleData.LoadData.html